# Refresh single query using VBA for multiple files in 1 folder

Tags: excel, vba

Refresh single query using VBA for multiple files in 1 folder.

I had a script that would refresh all, for all files in a given folder. It would open up the file in the background, refresh all, save, close the file and move onto the next. Now I want to edit the script to only update one query "NEW Linked List" in the files in the same folder.

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
Public Sub refreshfolder()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Path = "PATH ABC"  'the folder that contains the workbooks you want to refresh
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Path)
    
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With

    For Each file In folder.Files
        If Right(file.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(file.Name, 3) = "xls" Then
            Workbooks.Open Path & file.Name
            ActiveWorkbook.Connections("NEW Linked List").OLEDBConnection.Refresh
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
         End If
    Next

        With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The only issue is when I now run this, I get a runtime error '9' Subscript out of range error. The only change I made was changing ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll to ActiveWorkbook.Connections("NEW Linked List").OLEDBConnection.Refresh.

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: Likely the `ActiveWorkbook` has no connection with that name.